# Swift Array.indexOf containing nil values

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm working on an app and I need to know something, because I cannot continue without a solution to my problem. I have an array of the following type:

```
var samples : [HKSample?]!
```

Now I want to know if this array contains a specific element and what's the index of that element. When I'm trying to get the index like this

```
let anotherSample : HKSample = otherSamples.first
let index = samples.indexOf(anotherSample)
```

I get the following error:

```
"Cannot convert value of type 'HKSample?' to expected argument type '@noescpae (HKSample?) throws -> Bool'
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let anotherSample : HKSample = otherSamples.first
```

This is incorrect (and shouldn't compile). `first` will return `HKSample?` here.

Given that, you're searching for an `HKSample?` within an `[HKSample?]`. The problem is that `Optional` is not `Equatable`, so you have to use the predicate form of `indexOf`:

```
let index = samples.indexOf { $0 == anotherSample }
```

(where `anotherSample` is `HKSample?`, not `HKSample`.)

It is true that `Optional` has an `==` function available when its underlying type is `Equatable`, but it isn't itself `Equatable` because you can't currently conform to a protocol with a `where` clause. In order to make `Optional` conform, you'd have to be able to write:

```
extension Optional: Equatable where Wrapped: Equatable {}
```

But that's not currently supported in Swift. You'll get:

```
error: extension of type 'Optional' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause
```

Comment: But when I need the type 'HKSample?' and .first returns 'HKSample?' why isn't my approach working?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah; I was just writing that :D It suddenly occurred to me that it couldn't be ambiguous.

Comment: That sounds a bit complicated. I'm trying to find a workaround for that. :D But thank you very much!

Comment: `let index = samples.indexOf { $0 == anotherSample }` is complicated? That's very normal Swift.

Comment: I mean the extension for Optional etc.

Comment: `let index = samples.indexOf { $0 == anotherSample }` looks pretty good as "workaround".